# ARN of an AWS lamda function in custom-policies.json in AWS Amplify project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I need to invoke a lambda function from another lambda function.

Instead of hard coding, the arn of a function resource section of custom-policies.json file of a serverless function in AWS amplify project, how can I use the intrinsic function such as GetAtt/Ref etc?

custom-policies.json

```
[
    {
        "Action": ["lambda:InvokeFunction"],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function" // want to use function here, if possible.
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with Amplify, but could you replace the above ARN definition with: `arn:aws:lambda:${Region}:${Account}:function:my-function`.  I don't see a big issue with being explicit with the function name, and at least this way the region and account ID doesn't have to be specified. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsamplify.html#awsamplify-resources-for-iam-policies